# Scala Filter Chars from String

Tags: string, scala

I've got the following code which is supposed to count the numbers of times a character appears in a string.

```
  def filter[T] (l: List[T], stays: T ⇒ Boolean): List[T] = {
     if( l == Nil ) return Nil
     if (stays(l.head) == true) l.head :: filter(l.tail, stays)
     else filter(l.tail, stays)
  }


  def countChar(s: String): List[(Char, Int)] = {
    if (s == "") Nil
    else (s(0), s.count(_ == s(0))) :: countChar(filter(s.toList, _ == s(0)).mkString)
  }
```

Now my problem is that in

```
filter(s.toList, _ == s(0))
```

I get the error of: missing parameter type. I understand that this comes from nesting the function?

How can I fix this to work? I know that String has some methods to do what I want but I'd like to use my own filter method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's a limitation of Scala compiler: it tries to figure out what type `T` in `filter` should be, using both arguments `l` and `stays`. But it fails because the type of `stays` argument is unspecified.

If you don't want to specify the type of `stays` argument every time (i.e., `filter(s.toList, (_: Char) == s(0)`), you can split `filter`'s argument list into two:

```
def filter[T] (l: List[T])(stays: T ⇒ Boolean): List[T]
```

Then Scala will know that `T` is `Char` by the time it analyzes the type of `stays`. You can call this `filter` with `filter(l.tail)(stays)`.